# Copy a string into a char array

Tags: c

Hello i want to copy the input of a user into an array of char which is defined in a struct. Sincerly i have no idea how to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ()

{
    struct employee
    {
        char firstname[11];
        char lastname[11];
        char number[11];
        int salary;
    }

    int i;
    int nemps;
    const int maxemps = 5;
    struct employee* emps[maxemps];

    printf("How many employees do you want to store?(max:5): ");
    scanf("%d", nemps);

    for (i = 0; i < nemps; i++)
    {
        printf("Employee 1./nLast name:");
        scanf("....")// Read the string and copy it into char lastname[]
    }

}
```

Comment: you have a bug: `scanf("%d", nemps);` -> `scanf("%d", &nemps);`

Comment: You're also not allocating any actual `struct employee` objects.  If you want to use an array of pointers, you need `malloc` calls.  But just having an array of structs is simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off `struct employee* emps[maxemps];` creates an array of *pointers to struct employee* with array size *maxemps*.  You haven't actually set aside any space in memory for the actual structs, just the pointers that will point to them.  To dynamically allocate space on the heap for your structs so you can use them in a meaningful way, you'll need to loop over a call to `malloc()` like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < maxemps; i++) {
   emps[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
}
```

You'll also want a similar loop at the end of your program which will `free()` each pointer.

Next, when you are getting input from a user you really want to be using `fgets()` over `scanf()` because `fgets()` allows you to specify the number of characters to read in so you can prevent overflows on your destination buffer.

#### Update

If you want to work with a single `struct employee` without the use of pointers this is accomplished by declaring one or more `struct employee` on the stack and then using the `.` member access operator as follows:

```
struct employee emp;
fgets(emp.lastname, sizeof(emp.lastname), stdin);
```

#### Update2

I found a number of errors in your code. Please see [**this link**](http://ideone.com/kd5Zm) for a working sample with comments.

Comment: Ok lets say i just want to use one struct. So forget about the array of pointers to struct employee. Is there any possibility to access the char array in the struct employee without using a pointer?

Answer (score 2):

You only need:

```
scanf("%10s", (emps[i])->last_name);
```

Here `"%10s"` denotes a string with a maximum length of 10, and it will load the string to last_name.

In C the string is represented as a char array, with `'\0'` as the end.

Using `scanf` here is vulnerable to buffer attacks if the user-input is longer than 10: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf#Security, so you need to assign a maximum length to the format.

Comment: Thanks but what does "(emps[i])->last_name" mean?

Comment: @Ordo: that's a different question. `emps[i]` points to the i-th employee, which is a pointer to `struct employee`. The operator `->` takes the member `last_name` from the pointer. It is essentially the same as (*(emps[i])).last_name, but a little bit shorter. I suggest that you read some good tutorials on C programming, I think these questions are well explained there.

Comment: Did you note that he has to allocate memory for the employee (and initialize it) and that he can do scanf("%10s", ...) to limit the input? Also, he really should check the value of nemps before starting the loop.

Comment: @TToni, oh yes, I just focused on the parts he asked. `nemps` is better to be `unsigned`, and `scanf`-ed with `"%u"`.