# copy char to char array

Tags: c, char, arrays

I am trying to copy a "string" to array of strings in C:

```
const gchar  *strAuth, *strEditor, *strTitle; 
gchar *strings[18][150];
strcpy(strings[0],strAuth);
```

while compiling, gcc is giving warning: 
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Possibly, due to this fault of mine, the check and print in the later part of the code

```
  g_print("%s", strings[0]);
  int i=0;
  while (i <= 18) {
    if (strlen(strings[i]) != 0) {
      g_string_append_printf(tstring, "\t%s=\"%s\",\n",
      keyword[i], strings[i]);
      i++;
    } 
  }
```

is also not working (it is printing empty strings as well).
C is not my language, so kindly help

NB:thecked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205869/c-strcpy-copy-to-array-of-string) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477033/copy-a-string-into-a-char-array), but failed to help myself
NB:  gchar "Corresponds to the standard C char type." in glib

Comment: Potentially dangerous code. If you need fixed-length strings (150 bytes), use strncmp. P.S. type of strings[0] is gchar *[150] (that is an array of gchar's, like an array of strings, not _one_ string)

Comment: `strcpy` expects a `char*`, but it looks like you're passing it something closer to a `char**`. `strings` is a `char***`, so when you index it, it becomes a `char**`

Comment: @maverik,
so how can I make this less dangerous? It is also wastage of memory, as most of the entry is much less the 150b

Comment: @Rudra You could make an array of pointers and allocate memory for the strings dynamically.

Comment: @Lundin,
can you kindly provide me some example/links ?

Comment: @Rudra Please ask this as a separate question in another post.

Comment: @Lundin, a new question is created [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047017/array-of-pointers-and-allocate-memory-for-the-strings-dynamically/17047141?noredirect=1#17047141)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most immediate fix (without suggesting a totally different approach) requires a couple of fixes.

The thing about the warning is that you are creating an array of 18x150 pointers, but I guess you want 18 strings of length 150, so the definition should be:

```
gchar strings[18][150];  // 18 strings of 150 chars
```

The way your code looks, you would probably also assume to be zero initialized (empty strings if not filled) so you might add:

```
gchar strings[18][150]= { "", };  // 18 empty strings of 150 chars
```

.

Another (more severe) error in your code is that your loop is running [0...18].  But your list of strings is only `gchar *strings[18][150];`  so it should run [0..17].  Also the increment of I should also happen when length strings[i] is zero (otherwise you will get an infinite loop, never reaching the end if one string is empty).

```
  while (i < 18) {  // <-- FIX 
    if (strlen(strings[i]) != 0) {
      g_string_append_printf(tstring, "\t%s=\"%s\",\n",
      keyword[i], strings[i]);
    } 
    i++;  // <-- FIX 
  }
```

Comment: If it matters whether the strings are initialized or not, then the idiomatic way would perhaps have been to write `gchar strings[18][150] = {""}`, which sets all 18 strings to all-zeroes (all null termination).

Comment: @Rudra: Glad to hear :-).  Also, since you are appending strings, make sure that your tstring is long enough (something in the area of 18x150 bytes).

Answer (score 4):

You have not declared an array of strings. You have declared a 2D array of 18x150 pointers to char.

Therefore you get a warning: you are trying to copy a string, into an array of pointers.

An array of strings would have been `char strings [18][150]`.