# array of pointers and allocate memory for the strings dynamically

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

This question is connected to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046109/copy-char-to-char-array).
I am defining an array of characters, each of 150b, and copy a string to it as:

```
const gchar  *strAuth; 
gchar *strings[18][150];
strcpy(strings[0],strAuth);
```

which is huge memory wastage for most of the cases, and may be insufficient for some extreme cases.

As suggested in question referenced, it is a better idea to  "make an array of pointers and allocate memory for the strings dynamically."

How I can achieve this?
Kindly help.

Comment: Why cant you try with linked-list instead of using arrays? This solves memory wastage issue

Comment: @VoidPointer How exactly does it solve any memory wastage, compared to an array of pointers? The issue is the 150 bytes allocated per string, not the 4 bytes allocated by each pointer. So a linked-list doesn't really add anything here, especially since you would need additional overhead in the form of one next pointer per node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to allocate space for your strings, and assign the pointer it returns to your `gchar *strings[x]` for each x in strings you want to allocate. Something like this:

```
gchar *strings[18];
strings[0] = malloc(strlen(strAuth) + 1);
strcpy(strings[0], strAuth);
```

That's an array of pointers (line 1) and dynamic allocation of the memory for the string including the null terminator (line 2).

When you're done with a particular string in `strings`, you'll want to `free` it (see the same man page) with `free(strings[0]);`. I recommend you set any pointers that have been freed to NULL after freeing them.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
gchar *strings[18];
strings[5] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(gchar)*150); //to reserve space in memory
strcpy(strings[5],strAuth);
free (strings[5]); // to delete used buffer
```

Regards.